# File Contents read in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, google-books

I can obtain information form google books in PHP using the following code

```
 $page1 = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:1933372826")
 $data = json_decode($page1, true);
```

I have an array of 1,200+ ISBNs so I want to be able to get this files so I can read it

So for example if I get each element of the array that is ISBN to be `$book_isbn` I tried the following but I get an error

```
 $page2 = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:$book_isbn")
 $book_data = json_decode($page2, true);
```

What should I change? Can I have `$book_isbn` in the file_get_contents?

This is the error I get

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$book_data' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Comment: What error did you get?  Text of the error message, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$book_isbn = '1933372826';
$page2 = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:$book_isbn");
$book_data = json_decode($page2, true);
echo '<pre>';print_r($book_data);
```

If you have multiple value of book_isbn then use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and iterate over each element.

Comment: like a glove! Thank you!